# Submit button on mobile devices not unfocusing after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a follow but on my website that when clicked updates a DB via ajax.

After the success return, i change the class of the button to show a different background colour.

This works great on desktops, but on mobile devices the submit button remains active / has the hover action.

When hovering the submit i have hover event that changes the background colour just with a css :hover.

The div has the same colour that it would be if you hover it, but after the ajax response has changed the class.

Hope that make sense so far.

So i have a submit in a form:

```
<form>
  <input type="submit" id="followsubmit" class="followbuttonNO">
</form>
```

And on the correct response:

```
if (response.followSuccess) {
  $('#followsubmit').attr('class', 'followbuttonYES');
}
```

On a desktop, this code changes the class and button background colour changes (because the class has a different background colour...) but on a mobile device the button goes to the colour of the hover effect css.

If i click the submit button and then push anywhere else on the page before the response then it works fine.

TLDR; how to make a form submit button un focus after an ajax call? I have tried .blur() but that didnt work.

Thanks!

Comment: This will not necesserally help this case, but to change class you can better do this: `$('#followsubmit').removeClass('followbuttonNO').addClass('followbuttonYES');`

Comment: could you post your css? I assume it's `.followbuttonNO:hover {bg:color;}` and in `.followbuttonYES` not, but we can't be sure until we see it

Comment: correct. Its just a :hover for both the classes. Have just added the fact i am using fastclick.js which is great for removing the hover effect state on mobile devices. Maybe this is causing the issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that using hover for touchscreen's is tricky, because the `:hover` pseudo class looks for the actions pointing and selecting/activating. So on a touchscreen the action of clicking is essentially equivalent to hovering. So when you click on the submit button, it stays hovered until you deselect it.

A way to combat this would be for mobile/touchscreen devices make an on-click action and use `setTimeout()` with a short timer and change the classes.

I know you said you tried the `.blur()` but I am unsure of how you tried it. You need to set the blur function and then activate the trigger. Take a look below...

```
$('#followsubmit').blur(function(){
    //blur action
});

elsewhere...

$('#followsubmit').trigger('blur'); //execute blur action
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you say `blur` does not work, it has to work. Before binding any other functions to anchors or input fields, just add:

```
$('a, input').on('click', function(
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem and after few hours I've fixed this with CSS media query:

```
@media (any-hover: hover) {
  a:hover {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```